# Python get image matrix PIL

Tags: python, numpy, python-imaging-library

i am trying to get to load an image, convert it and print the matrix. I have the following code ;

```
im = Image.open("1.jpg")
im = im.convert("L")
print im
```

when i print 'im' i get this `<PIL.Image.Image image mode=L size=92x112 at 0x2F905F8>` . How can i get to see the image matrix?

Answer (score 17):

You can use `numpy.asarray()`:

```
>>> import Image, numpy
>>> numpy.asarray(Image.open('1.jpg').convert('L'))
```

Answer (score 5):

Function load will give you access to pixels like this:

```
b = im.load()
print b[x,y]
b[x,y] = 128    # or a tupple if you use another color mode
```

Answer (score 2):

`im.show()` will display it in a pop-up window.

`im.tostring()` will dump the image as a byte string.

`im.save()` to save it to a file.

Comment: `im.tostring()` is now replaced by `im.tobytes()`